# HTML5 input type calendar, color and range

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

While developing my website I met some trouble concerning the compatibility between browsers like Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Also I have this code, on the head of my document:

```
   <!-- HTML5 Shim -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->     
        <!-- Modernizr -->
        <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
        <!-- Webforms2 -->

        <!-- jQuery  -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Color Picker -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorpicker.css">
        <script src="colorpicker.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Numeric Spinner -->
        <script src="spinner.js"></script>  
            <!-- jQuery Placehol 
            <script src="jquery.placehold-0.2.min.js"></script>  -->
```

On the body of my page I have:

```
 <!-- Script DATE  -->
    <script>
    var initDatepicker = function() {  
    $('input[type=date]').each(function() {  
        var $input = $(this);  
        $input.datepicker({  
            minDate: $input.attr('min'),  
            maxDate: $input.attr('max'),  
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'  
        });  
    });  
};  

if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.date){  
    $(document).ready(initDatepicker);  
};  
  </script>

  <!-- Script COLOR  -->
  <script>
  var initColorpicker = function() {  
    $('input[type=color]').each(function() {  
        var $input = $(this);  
        $input.ColorPicker({  
            onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {  
                $(el).val(hex);  
                $(el).ColorPickerHide();  
            }  
        });  
    });  
};  

if(!Modernizr.inputtypes.color){  
    $(document).ready(initColorpicker);  
};  
  </script>


<!-- Script Slider -->
<script>
var initSlider = function() {  
    $('input[type=range]').each(function() {  
        var $input = $(this);  
        var $slider = $('<div id="' + $input.attr('id') + '" class="' + $input.attr('class') + '"></div>');  
        var step = $input.attr('step');  

        $input.after($slider).hide();  

        $slider.slider({  
            min: $input.attr('min'),  
            max: $input.attr('max'),  
            step: $input.attr('step'),  
            change: function(e, ui) {  
                $(this).val(ui.value);  
            }  
        });  
    });  
};
</script>
```

The problem I have is concerning the PHP page, because when I'm on index.php all works fine.

When I go on `index.php?p=som_page` and no matter of what is the argument on p that script does not work anymore.

I'm a bit lost, because on the page I have only include function with no head and no body just the div that are included.

But when I turn back on index.php all works fine again.

This problem hapen only when I'm on Firefox or internet explorer. When I use Chrome all works fine with the input type date, color or range.

Comment: I found the title and explanation a bit confusing. It may lead to think your problem is with the input elements when it isn't. Maybe you could rephrase it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `<input type="color" name="favcolor">` is not supported by IE, Firefox, or Safari.  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp